# Как выделить часть проекта удаленным программистам

Tags: git

У нас есть большой проект, в последнее время стало трудной задачей набрать программистов в команду в офис. Все хотят работать удаленно а нам не хватает разработчиков. Хотим набрать разработчиков удаленно. Но возникает вопрос, как выделить удаленному разработчику часть проекта, которая касается к конкретной к его задаче? Мы не можем весь проект дать клонировать только частично. Если мы наш проект разделим на несколько репозиториев, то удаленный разработчик, как будет работать с частью проекта, как будет тестировать, ведь проект разбросанный же получается. Как решают такие задачи большие проекты? Куда копать?

Comment: по хорошему выделяют кусок в виде какой то библиотеки и для нее пишут тесты. Все, теперь удаленный (то есть того, которого удалили:) ) может работать над своим куском.

Comment: если речь идет конкретно про разделение в git, то одним из решений могут быть  git submodules

Comment: «проект надо разделить, но разделять нельзя» — только мне кажется, что эти два поставленных условия несовместимы между собой?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin надо разделить - это с точки зрения конфиденциальности и кражи. А про "нельзя" я ничего не говорил.

Comment: `как будет тестировать` — свою часть проекта разработчик должен сам покрыть тестами (на выполнение поставленных перед ним задач), а тестированием всего проекта целиком должны заниматься тестировщики, которым вообще не нужен доступ к исходникам. т.е. начать вам надо с разделения одного большого проекта на несколько более мелких составляющих.

Comment: А чем разрабы, работающие удалённо, отличаются от тех, кто работает в офисе? Почему нельзя дать им доступ ко всему проекту? У меня за пять лет удаленной работы ни разу не было такой проблемы

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения git это просто отдельный репозиторий. Важно структурировать проект соответствующим образом.

Выделяете часть функционала в отдельную библиотеку или даже сервис. Расскажу про библиотеку (с сервисами похоже, но все чуть на другом уровне).

Для библиотеки создаете отдельный git репозиторий. Разработчик работает с ним, тестирует саму библиотеку изолированно. После того, как изменения сделаны, новая версия публикуется (это может быть и версия чисто для тестирования). Для этого нужна процедура публикации. Это может быть какой-то скрипт, который  собирает библиотеку и публикует ее в внутренний репозиторий артефактов.

Для java экосистемы это может быть maven репозиторий, для python - pypi, для nodejs - npm репозиторий, думаю идея понятна.

Остальные библиотеки/модули используют библиотеку точно так же как и другие библиотеки, т.е. в зависимостях указывают название и версию. Далее на dev/тестовом окружении для сборки нужно подключить этот внутренний репозиторий, т.е. чтоб можно было использовать новую опубликованную версию.

Теперь пользователи этой библиотеки - разработчики других модулей или система, которая делает развертывание на тестовом окружении, могут использовать новую опубликованную версию. Для этого нужно будет зависимые модули изменить и в них указать новую версию.

Так можно протестировать интеграцию новой версии библиотеки.